# MongoDB - count by field, and sort by count

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB, and new to making more than super basic queries and i didn't succeed to create a query that does as follows:

I have such collection, each document represents one "use" of a benefit (e.g first row states the benefit "123" was used once):

```
[
    {
    "id" : "1111",
    "benefit_id":"123"
    },
    {
    "id":"2222",
    "benefit_id":"456"
    }, 
    {
    "id":"3333",
    "benefit_id":"456"
    },
    {
    "id":"4444",
    "benefit_id":"789"
    }
]
```

I need to create q query that output an array. at the top is the most top used benefit and how many times is was used.

for the above example the query should output:

```
[
    {
    "benefit_id":"456",
    "cnt":2
    },
    {
    "benefit_id":"123",
    "cnt": 1
    }, 
    {
    "benefit_id":"789",
    "cnt":1
    }
]
```

I have tried to work with the documentation and with `$sortByCount` but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### $group

- `$group` by `benefit_id` and get count using `$sum`
- `$sort` by `count` descending order

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$benefit_id",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { count: -1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/71BgFgsXfT8)

---

#### $sortByCount

Same operation using `$sortByCount` operator

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sortByCount: "$benefit_id" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eo_sgDgzz1b)